# Pasting in MSI Installer TextBoxs

Tags: installation, windows-installer

We are upgrading our installers to MSI, and have noticed that you can not "right click and paste" into the text boxes. You can however ctrl+v. Is there a setting that you can switch on to enable context menus within the installer?

Answer (score 2):

The MSI native UI is horribly primitive, though pretty clever considering it's expressed using a set of database tables ;)

If you need to exercise any degree of control over the UI then you would be better off writing your own front-end interview applet to build up a set of configuration parameters and using that to launch the install with a minimal UI, passing the the parameters in as a set of installer properties.

Comment: And you can External UI so that installation progress is displayed in front-end application UI.

Answer (score 0):

MSI subclasses the controls it displays, the `WndProc` for edit controls which MSI sets for edit controls may be implemented in a way that it does not pass right-click events to the original `WndProc`, and therefore context menu is not displayed.

There's no setting that you can enable context menu functionality.